# C# WinForm progress bar not progressively increasing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I've made a simple Mp3 to Wave converter using NAudio. Everything works fine, except that there is a bug that I really don't like. Here's the section of the code that does the conversion:

```
    foreach (mp3file file in fileList){
        string outputfilename = fbd.SelectedPath + "\\" + file.name + ".wav";
        using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(file.path)){
            using (WaveStream convertedStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader)){
               WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputfilename, convertedStream);
            }
        }
        progressBar.PerformStep(); //This isn't working.
    }
```

I wanted the program to make the progressbar perform a step each time a song gets converted, but instead the progress bar stays empty for the entire conversion process and then increases all at once when the conversion is finished.
It's not that worrying tho, if there's not simple solution I'll bear this bug.

Comment: becuase `progressBar.PerformStep();` has to be in the loop instead of outside the loop. just cut and paste one step before.

Comment: I can't believe I've missed that...

Comment: No wait, I just poorly copied the code in the post, I'll fix it, `progressBar.PerformStep()` is indeed inside the loop.

Comment: Your braces don't look like they're lined up properly... Are you sure that line is inside the foreach loop?

Comment: Yeah, first question on this site, I'm not very experienced with the posting syntax, but I can assure you that the code in my compiler is alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Conversion and progressbar updation is taking place on same thread so updating the GUI components do not take place until the conversion is completed just use `Application.doEvents()` as it will process all pending messages in que of application after `progressbar.PerformStep()` then it will not fill up at once at the end of processing but keeps on updating with the processing

```
foreach (mp3file file in fileList){
        string outputfilename = fbd.SelectedPath + "\\" + file.name + ".wav";
        using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(file.path)){
            using (WaveStream convertedStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader)){
               WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputfilename, convertedStream);
            }
        }
        progressBar.PerformStep(); //This isn't working alone
        Application.DoEvents();   //This is working fine now
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using either [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) or [async and await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) to perform for progress bar updates. The loops generally block the WinForms and it looks like it is freezed and nothing is happening. Whereas the `BackgroundWorker` reports the UI thread if any changes has been made.

**In the constructor**

```
{
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

**BackgroundWorker implementation**

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    foreach (mp3file file in fileList)
    {
        string outputfilename = fbd.SelectedPath + "\\" + file.name + ".wav";
        using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(file.path))
        {
            using (WaveStream convertedStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader)){
            WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputfilename, convertedStream);
        }
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress();
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something When the loop or operation is completed.
}
```

Comment: I will need to do some research about it, it's really something I've never used and I fail to understand how to implement it. For instance, when is `backgroundWorker_doWork(...)` called?

Comment: In the first line of the answer is the link where u can find more about BackgroundWorker. Next you need to call `dowork` when u want the loop to be implemented for you.

Comment: I think I've implemented it the way you said, but It raises some cross-thread exception at the `foreach` line

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is all taking place on the UI thread, try calling the Refresh() method on the progress bar object, to force it to redraw.

```
foreach (mp3file file in fileList){
        string outputfilename = fbd.SelectedPath + "\\" + file.name + ".wav";
        using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(file.path)){
            using (WaveStream convertedStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader)){
            WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputfilename, convertedStream);
        }
        progressBar.PerformStep(); // This isn't working.
        progressBar.Refresh();     // This might fix it
    }
```

But it's better to offload this sort of work to a BackgroundWorker.